# Autocommit Migration from Django 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: python, django

I was migrating from Django 1.7 to 1.8 via following steps

1. Active virtualenv
2. Uninstall Django 1.7
3. Install Django 1.8
4. python manage.py runserver

On execution of step 4 for I am getting the following error.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f4e473a8230>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 223, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 164, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 180, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/lenovo/Envs/boilerplate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: invalid connection option "autocommit"
```

Error seems to be from psycopg2 module and related to autocommit. In the **feature removed** section of 1.8 documentation I found the following line.

```
the decorators and context managers autocommit, commit_on_success, and commit_manually, defined in django.db.transaction
```

I couldn't relate this to the error I got. Can somebody throw light into this?

### Update:

I found out why. Below is my DB connection config. In that there is autocommit=True. On commenting that line, the issue got resolved. But still I want to know why we cannot give autocommit=True option.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'NAME': 'bp_django_auth',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'abcd1234',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "autocommit": True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following was outlined in the [Django 1.7 Databases docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#autocommit-mode):

> In previous versions of Django, database-level autocommit could be enabled by setting the autocommit key in the OPTIONS part of your database configuration in DATABASES.
>
> Since Django 1.6, **autocommit is turned on by default**. This configuration is ignored and can be safely removed.

And as per the [1.8 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#features-removed-in-1-8), this feature was removed.

If you still want to keep the setting for some reason, simply move it out of `OPTIONS`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'NAME': 'bp_django_auth',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'abcd1234',
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    }
}
```